# Better way to code this ? Set multiple variables as values for one str(key) in a dictionary

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I wrote the following function. The output values should be used as part of parameters in a api request

```
def zeitraum():
    x = input("How many month? Choose between 1 and 24 \n")
    y = []
    z = {'a string key':y}
    for i in range(1,int(x)+1):
        if int(x) > 24:
            x = input("Choose between 1 and 24. \n")
        if i <= 12:
            x = f'year1month{i}'
            y.append(x)
        else:
            x = f'year2month{i-12}'
            y.append(x)
    return z

d = zeitraum()
print (d)
```

** Output **

```
How many month? Choose between 1 and 24 
13
{'a string key': ['year1month1', 'year1month2', 'year1month3', 'year1month4', 'year1month5', 'year1month6', 'year1month7', 'year1month8', 'year1month9', 'year1month10', 'year1month11', 'year1month12', 'year2month1']}
```

Is there a better way to code this?

EDIT: With Yevhens,VPfB and zwers comments I rewrote the code:

```
def zeitraum():
    
    while True:
        x = input("How many month? Choose between 1 and 24 \n")
        if 1 <= int(x) <= 24:
            break
        else:
            print ("Wrong input! \n")
    
    return {'a key': [f"year{m//12+1}month{m%12+1}" for m in range(int(x))]}
```

Comment: This question probably belongs here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com. But my suggestion: name variables with meaningful names. If users' first input is invalid (i.e. `x>24`), it will produce an incorrect result because your `for` loop will have a number of iterations equal to the first inputted value.

Comment: Also, your code will fail anyway because you use `x` variable to store your `'year...'` string and then trying to convert it into an integer on the second iteration. Please, try running your code before posting it here.

Comment: Hello @Yevhen, ok I will post it to codereview.
To your second comment. As the input returns a string I use `x` to concatenate with the `'year...' `and I used `int(x)` as a range parameter to do the for loop.
The code worked for me in Jupyter Notebook. The output I copied from it. It didnt give an error.

Comment: I mean the `int(x)` in your if statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm posting just the core

This will work for any positive integer `x`:

```
return {'a key': [f"year{m//12+1}month{m%12+1}" for m in range(x)]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can greatly simplify this by generating the whole list in one go, something like:

```
def zeitraum():
    x = input("How many months? Choose between 1 and 24 \n")
    y = ['year{}month{}'.format(m // 12 + 1, m % 12 + 1) for m in range(int(x))]
    z = {'a string key': y}
    return z
```

You don't even need to limit it to just 24 months—integer division with 12 will always return the year number and modulo with 12 will always give you the exact month of the year.